# how to loop through this template... I'd like to generate the items of a list

Tags: python, rawstring

```
question_template =r''' 
%-----------------QUESTION-----------------------------------------
\item 
\input{{{i}}}
\n
'''
for i in range(0,10):
    question_template+=question_template.format(i)
```

I'm getting this error.

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
6 '''
7 for i in range(0,10):
----> 8     question_template+=question_template.format(i)

KeyError: 'i'

the syntax with the '' is from latex
I need that 3 {, for the code run on the latex properly.

It's a script that generates exams based on questions stored in a folder. I want to run through the folder and generate various questions depending on the number of questions in the folder.

I'd like to generate something like this.

```
''' 
%-----------------QUESTION-----------------------------------------
\item 
\input{{{0}}}

%------------------QUESTION------------------------------------------
\item 
\input{{{1}}}

%----------------QUESTION--------------------------------------------
\item 
\input{{{2}}}

%-----------------QUESTION-----------------------------------------------
\item 
\input{{{3}}}

%----------------QUESTION---------------------------------------------
\item 
\input{{{4}}}
```

Comment: You need `\input{{{{i}}}}` to do the substitution, and then use `.format(i=i)`.  That should do it.

Comment: Didn't work. The loop didn't return an error nether constructed the template changing the index numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet, that is quick and dirty but worked for me.

```html
question_template =r''' 
%-----------------QUESTION-----------------------------------------
\item 
\input{{{'''

part2 = '''}}}
\n
'''
for i in range(0,10):
    print(question_template,i,part2)
```

Comment: I needed to write a file with that part...couldn't use the print but got the spirit and actually solved the problem! Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You were modifying the template each time, instead of building a new string.  This works.

```
question_template =r''' 
%-----------------QUESTION-----------------------------------------
\item 
\input{{{i}}}
\n
'''
qt = ''
for i in range(0,10):
    qt+=question_template.format(i=i)
print(qt)
```